# Código em java causa problema no persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, classes

Após acrescentar as seguintes linhas a minha classe MetaDicas.java, surgiu um problema no persistence que não havia antes:

Linhas adicionadas:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn
private List<Integer> notas;
```

Erro:

```
>javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: h2PersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
 org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
 org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
 org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
 javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
 javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
 play.db.jpa.JPAPlugin.onStart(JPAPlugin.java:38)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
 play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
 play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:157)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130)
 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128)
 scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:120)
 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
 scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
 scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Tentei de diversas maneiras mas não consegui corrigi-lo de maneira alguma.

Comment: Erick, não sei o que você pretende fazer, mas não pode fazer um Join com uma lista de inteiros dessa forma. Assim como eu, o Hibernate não vai adivinhar de onde ele deve recuperar essa lista. O jeito normal de fazer isso é ter uma lista de alguma outra entidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve especificar mais a coluna que voce quer juntar. Por Exemplo:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "web_usuario_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_role", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private List<Papel> authorities;
```

Não acho que seja possivel fazer a junção com um List de Inteiros.

Answer (score 0):

O que o

> ti.sof002

disse é correto.
Porem, tome muito cuidado com FetchType.EAGER e FetchType.Lazy. isso pode causar algumas encomodações para você. (sistema lento, error "LazyInitializeException, Nullpointer", etc.)

Quando precisar trazer uma lista populada, é mais performatico popular a lista com uma namedQuery.

```
/* Não é recomentado usar EAGER em mapeamentos OneToMany, pois quando este objeto for recuperado vai trazer a lista desse objeto e seus sub-objetos todos populados, issso pode deixar o sistema lento. Por padrão um mapeamento OneToMany já é Lazy, mas pode colocar para facilitar a leitura do código.*/
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)     
@JoinTable(name = "web_usuario_role", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_role", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private List<Papel> authorities;
```

Abraço
comentarios e criticas são bem vindas  :-)